# saving an item to a list in discord.py and then sending it to server

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot which allows me to add items into a list when I say a command, then when I say a different command it will say the list in the discord server. This is my code so far.

```
hwk = ["test"]

@bot.event 
  async def on_message(message):
  message.content = message.content.lower()
  if message.content.startswith("#add"):  
    await bot.send_message(message.channel, "what would you like to add to 
    your list?")
    msg = await bot.wait_for_message(timeout=10, author=message.author)
    if msg:
        hwk.append(str(msg))
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, "added to list")

  if message.content.startswith("#hwk"):

    values = ",".join(map(str, hwk))
    await bot.send_message(message.channel, values)
```

but when the bot says the message in the server it comes up saying test,discord.message.Message object at 0x0000026738F986A0 in the server. Not as code.

not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: save `msg.content` to the list instead of `str(msg`).

Comment: i've gotta say whenever u say those short and simple solutions i feel so stupid. Thx man, works perfectly